# BizTalk - sharing a schema with promoted properties

Tags: properties, schema, biztalk

In our BizTalk application we would like all internal messages to have the same structure, with a Header element with routing and logging information (this header is the same for all messages), all properties of which are promoted, and a Body element which is different for each specific message. When I create a new message based on the above (by setting the schema's DataStructure or BaseType), I would like the promotions to be kept as well.

I tried getting this to work by creating a Header message with the required fields and promotions, and also by creating a "complete" BaseMessage with a Header and Body element (again with all properties in the header promoted), but either way in a schema using this DataStructure the property promotions are not kept (which I guess makes sense; the XPaths indicated in the PropertySchema are different, because the BaseMessage namespace is different from the derived message).

Is there a way to have a shared schema including property promotions? Or can you copy the structure in a derived message, but you always have to redo the promotions?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar header structure that is imported and always have to redo the promotions.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to solve this problem by not doing what you're describing.  While it sounds good in theory, you will find eventually that it's over-engineering with little practical benefit.

What will matter is the routing information, meaning, the Properties, not the Header section. So, it's fine to have shared Property Schemas (deployed separately) but don't try to shoehorn the messages into a 'common' wrapper.